# Chromebook hover feature

Tags: chromebook

I am delighted with my Chromebook, apart from the hover feature. That is driving me mad. I have seen one forum contributor who starts off "Go to Settings" That is OK. Then he says "Go to Advanced Settings". That heading/icon does not exist on my machine.

Surely somebody has discovered how to disable this feature?

Comment: What does this question have to do with Excel?

Comment: [chromebook - how do i stop the hover feature?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromebook-central/EEnxdw6SDLw): Look at the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for this post being so late,but I just received my Chromebook. The answer to your question about the hover feature is: Go to settings, click on the advanced settings. Under the the Accessibility settings you will see the Manage accessibility features, click on it. Under the accessibility features you will see the Mouse and touchpad feature, turn off the switch that says automatically click when the cursor stops.

Answer (score 0):

To find the Advanced Settings, scroll down to the bottom of the Settings page.  You should find a clickable link, "Show advanced settings...." at the very bottom.  Click this to open Advanced Settings.

That said, I don't know of any way to disable hover in these settings.